# Smart Card : Class N terminal for geolocation api testing

Tags: smartcard, globalplatform

I have developed `UICC.usim.geolocation` api.
But for testing this feature I need class N terminal. This class is mentioned in terminal profile returned.

Can anyone help me to get any input related to class N terminal (mobile)?

Comment: There is a public [terminal profile database](https://terminal-profile.osmocom.org/). You may check here if any of the reported phones support class "n"..Good luck!

Comment: No, there is no such terminal with class "n"support.

Comment: Please let me know if anyone konws about it.